# Using rewind() with popen()

Tags: c, unix

I have a simple C code snippets as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  FILE *f;
  char c;
  f = popen("ls", "r");
  while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    //Some tasks
  }
  rewind(f);
  while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

I don't know why the code output nothing. It seems the rewind() function doesn't work. Please help find out where I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: you're reading output from a program. just because you can `rewind()` a file handle doesn't mean that `ls` will know you rewound and should restart its listing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rewind` is equivalent to `fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET)` and `fseek` is only legal on files, not streams (which is the case with pipes).

Check the `errno` after `rewind` it should be

> EBADF  The stream specified is not a seekable stream.

Comment: `ESPIPE` I hope. I never noticed before that `rewind` returns void. That seems like a design error.

Comment: We can't seek on pipes? Why so? Is there any way to rewind the stream in this situation?

Comment: @Phieu you can't seek on pipes because the pipe is just a small kernel memory buffer that temporarily holds data between the time it is generated by the writer and consumed by the reader. After you've read it, the writer and the kernel no longer have it. You have it, and if you want to have it later, you have to find a place to keep it. Rewinding a pipe, a socket, or a serial port is an attempt to travel back in time, and unix doesn't do causality violations.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks for letting me know these useful information. I really need to dive in those things more deeply. Could you offer me some references from which you learn? Thanks again.

Comment: While this answer illustrated what is wrong, it did not help provide an alternative solution. This leaves anyone who wants to get the desired result clueless.. I for one am wondering, is it better to figure out a way to store the output of the popen read command?? or to just execute it twice?

Comment: @bazz Both are valid resolutions of this problem. Which one to go with depends entirely on your use case. What is more costly in your runtile system: memory (e.g. embedded system) to cache the output or time to rerun (e.g. realtime system)? The answer to that is not obvious from the question.

Comment: In my case, I would like to conserve time, I will maybe think of a way to implement the solution and post a response answer, although I have already simply solved by running popen twice, without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer: Rewind using memstream

As has already been stated by others, you cannot rewind a pipe. What hasn't been said is what a good solution might be. The answer is fortunately simple, at least on UNIX, use [memstream](https://manpages.debian.org/open_memstream) to buffer the data into memory as a stream which you *can* rewind.

### TL;DR

```
FILE *mem = open_memstream(NULL, NULL);
while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
  fputc(c, mem);
  //...Some tasks...
}
rewind(mem);
```

### About memstreams

A memstream is a dynamically allocated buffer in memory which you can treat like a file. It works like any other C stream so there's no need to learn a new interface.

It has been part of the POSIX standard for a long time and works on all modern UNIX systems. Implementations are included in the C library of both GNU & BSD based systems, such as Debian and MacOS.

### Alternatives

The simplest answer, opening the pipe again certainly works most of the time and is trivial to do. However, it would not be a good idea to use that technique if the data is not guaranteed to be identical each time. Also, some programmers may find it irksome to write such obviously suboptimal code.

Manually reading the data into an array is a reasonable alternative, but may not be feasible in certain situations where a stream is required, for example with certain libraries (e.g., libpng) or programming frameworks (e.g., lex parsing). Additionally, arrays cans be more complex to code depending upon how the memory is allocated.

### Full code

Here is what the example code in the question would look like using memstream.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>        /* For err() */
void main() {
  FILE *f, *mem;
  int c;
  f = popen("ls", "r");
  mem = open_memstream(NULL, NULL);
  if (mem == NULL)
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "open_memstream");

  while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    fputc(c, mem);
    // ... Some tasks ...
  }
  pclose(f);

  rewind(mem);
  while ((c = fgetc(mem)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
  }
  fclose(mem);
}
```

### Downsides

The downside is that memstream is not part of the C standard. It probably won't work in Microsoft Windows unless you bring your own implementation. (See: [Equivalent of open_memstream for MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864178/equivalent-of-open-memstream-for-msvc)).